# YouTube - can't add videos to my lists anymore

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

if I see an interesting video I used to click + and add it do my list. Recently it stopped working and it forever says "loading lists" with loading circle. Actually now I see it might be Chrome problem because it works in MS Edge. Anybody had this problem too and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Try the following 1/ disable extension 2/ new chrome profile 3/ reinstall chrome.

Comment: Delete the cache and history completely and restart chrome to try it.